# spring web flow builder services: when does one need it?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

I have read that spring flow builder services are used to "customize" a web flow. Now my question: When does one need to customize a web flow? Could somebody give me a concrete example?

Regards and thanks in advance.
H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use another el expression parser, or a view factory creator to use webflow with Tiles, to set up your own conversion service, set your app for development (which allows you to dynamically change your flows without having to restart you server)